# No puedo pasarle un Id variable al getElementById()

Tags: javascript, html, string, variables

Estoy intentando hacer getElementById() de una variable numerica pero me sale el error

> "document.getElementById is not a function "

```
/* ejemplo : quiero poner "reintegrado" en los elementos con id = "1", obviamente lo necesito para una variable numerica que va cambiando segun los datos ingresados*/

var num = 1;
document.getElementById(num).InnerHTML = "reintegrado" ;
```

Comment: "document.getElementById is not a function "

Comment: Este código dónde lo estás ejecutando? En un navegador o en Node?

Comment: En un navegador, igualmente es un ejemplo de como le paso la variable al getElementById pero no es el codigo real .. lo que no se es como pasarle la variable sin poner las comillas ya que no me lo toma

Comment: No me di cuenta, es `innerHTML`

Comment: Revisa si por algún motivo has sobreescrito el método `getElementById` mediante alguna asignación. Por ejemplo: `document.getElementById = "algo";` sobreescribirá el método por la cadena `algo`. Si luego intentas usar `document.getElementById(num)` te arrojará un error ya que `getElementById` ya no es una función, sino una cadena. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Le estas pasando un div con id que no existe.
estas escribiendo mal el innerHTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    var re = document.getElementById('1').innerHTML = "reintegrado" ;
    console.log(re);
</script>

<div id="1"></div>
```

Comment: El problema es solo lo segundo.

Comment: @E.Betanzos el problema no es sólo lo segundo, entiendo que `InnerHTML` es un typo, pero igualmente es un nombre de propiedad válido, que lamentablemente no será pintado en el DOM, pero de hecho la asignación es válida. En su [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/369020/no-puedo-pasarle-un-id-variable-al-getelementbyid#comment662134_369020) el OP plantea que el error está en el nombre de la función. Es posible que haya asignado otra cosa al atributo `getElementById`, ejemplo: `document.getElementById = "algo"` en algún momento anterior y esto cause la sobreescritura del método.

Answer (score 0):

No me a quedado muy claro debido a que no veo el echo de como lo quieres ejecutar pero pienso que lo que quieres es ejecutar al momento de cargar la pagina. Prueba colocan dolos en una función y utiliza "window.onload = 'nombre de la función()' " para ser llamada cuando cargue.

```js
window.onload = f1;

function f1(){
var num = 1;
document.getElementById(num).innerHTML = "reintegrado";
}
```

```html
<p id="1"></p>
```